# Differentiating the CDF of a transformed random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a random variable, $x$, distributed with CDF $G(x)$ and PDF $g(x)$ on $[0,1]$. I am trying to determine the derivative of $G(x-a)$ with respect to $x$, where $a>0$. My intuition is that I should first differentiate $G(x-a)$ with respect to $(x-a)$, giving $g(x-a)$, and then (x-a) with respect to $x$, which is $1.$ Thus I get $g(x-a)$. Is my thinking correct? Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. This is a direct consequence of the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct and it is very easy to prove

$$G_X(x-a)=\int_0^{x-a}g_X(t)dt$$

$$G_X'(x-a)=g_X(x-a)\times 1=g_X(x-a)$$